# Passing value from Parent LWC to picklist in Child LWC using handleRowAction

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to pass picklist value from parent lwc to lightning combobox in child lwc.
I am calling below child component(as shown in screenshot) from parent component.
[image]

Child component is called on handleRowACtion using below code

```
case 'View':
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes: {url: 'https://dev2022sb-adscardservices.cs210.force.com/ComenityBusinessCenter/s/account-lookup'
}
});
```

So my requirement is to pass "Account Number" as selected value for Search for Accountby. 
Below code is used in child component for picklist

```
<lightning-combobox name="search_account" label="Search for Account by:"
                     placeholder="Select Option" value={value} options={searchAccountByOptions}
                     onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to attain this you will first need to pass the value to the child which would then place it in the combobox.

[This link shows how to pass values to children components](https://www.sfdckid.com/2020/08/api-property-lightning-web-component.html)

https://www.sfdckid.com/2020/08/api-property-lightning-web-component.html

you would then use the name of the variable declared as api, in your lightning-combobox markup

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.